# DCOM CoCreateInstanceEx E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: c++, windows, dcom

I am working with 2 PCs, both running both running Windows XP. Both have the same application registered with its DCOM interface. Now i'm trying to start the program from one computer on the other.

First I called CoInitializeSecurity, after that CoCreateInstanceEx, but the result is a E_ACCESSDENIED.

I did also run dcomcnfg, to give anyone access, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the user explicitly and give him all permissions. After that it works.

Answer (score 1):

access is ONE choice under dcom... you also need Launch and Activation settings...  I'd hit that next...

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant them, too. I gave remote access and activation to everyone in Launch& Activation and Access Permissions...